# How to Root Galaxy S5 (SM-G900A) running Lollipop 5.1.1?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-5

## Background:

I currently am in the process of trying to root an Android smartphone with the following device info:

> Device Model: Samsung-SAMSUNG-SM-G900A
>   Android Version: 5.1.1
>   Build Number: LMY47X.G900AUCS4CPA3

While I have attempted to use all of the following products, they all failed to root, leaving a message that my device was *"Not Supported"*:

- Kingo Root ([Android App](https://www.kingoapp.com/))
- towelroot ([Android App](https://towelroot.com/))
- OneClickRoot (Windows App)

## My Questions:

1. Given these device stats, is there ANY way for me to root my device?
2. If yes, how can I go about it?
3. If no, why not?

Comment: Link to OneClickRoot: search4roots.com/download

Comment: This question was copied directly from http://superuser.com/questions/1089319/can-this-android-be-rooted , as per the requests of the Super User community.

Comment: Based on [a thread on AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5-rooting-roms-hacks/635893-t-there-still-no-root.html#post4970035), seems AT&T locked it, and no one has ever succeed in rooting it since then.

Comment: AndrewT so there's absolutely no hope of hacking past their lockout, then?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Compared to XDA forum, this community doesn't have much expertise on rooting every variance of Android device. If XDA, which I've known as the biggest Android modding/rooting community, haven't done it, then I'm afraid it's really impossible. Hopefully someone can prove me wrong though.

Comment: Andrew T. What a shame. I was really looking forward to being able to manage the kernel on my own. Regardless, thank you very much for all of your help!

Comment: Someone honest installing the kernel that are installed in the verdion 4.4 KitKat, perhaps installing another kernel to 100% LOLLIPOP could Root sm-g900a.

Comment: Mrmaycol That's an excellent idea, if it's possible. The trouble is I have no idea how to go about downgrading my kernel, although if you could help me to figure out how, and then write an answer detailing how, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment by [@AndrewT.](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/44325/andrew-t), it appears that AT&T have locked the device against rooting (corrected the exploits used by these one-click root solutions back with Android 5.0).

From the [link](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5-rooting-roms-hacks/635893-t-there-still-no-root.html#post4970035) in the comment:

<sub>Emphasis and comments mine</sub>

> ...the fact remains that AT&T's Android 4.4.4, released in 2014, and Android 5.0 and 5.1.1, released in 2015, have all been unrootable and no-one in the worldwide rooting community has found a root method apart from downgrading to the AT&T, Android 4.4.2, NCE, firmware/kernel... [to get] an exploit that AT&T **closed off almost year ago with Android 5.0**. Make no mistake, this is not Google or Samsung preventing you from rooting... it is all down to your carriers, AT&T and Verizon.

This post appears to be from a reputed member of their community, so we can be reasonably assured that even the great people at XDA-Developers (AT&T SGS5 thread [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/att-galaxy-s5)) have not managed to root this particular device (see [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=67181840&postcount=3)).

Hence, we can say that as of now there is no way to root this particular device (AT&T Samsung Galaxy S5) on this particular Android version (5.1).